# jquery select multiple values in a select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have select box (multiple attribute), called "c0r1", it contains the options:

```
<select id="c0r1" multiple="multiple" class="fcv">
     <option value="A">A</option>
     <option value="B">B</option>
     <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

I also have the object "foo"

```
 "foo" : {
       "bar": ["x", "y", "z"],
       "teal" : [
            {"x" : ["A"], "y" : [...], "z" : [...]},
            {"x" : [...], "y" : [...], "z" : [...]},
            {"x" : [...], "y" : [...], "z" : [...]}
        ]
 }
```

bar stores a set of values, which are then used as keys in the objects in the teal array.

The contents of c0r1 (and c0r2, c1r1, ...) are determined by "x", "y", and "z". Elsewhere in the code, they represent a group of values. The page assigns the select box a group, and the options are filled in from the group (the first piece of HTML was generated in this way).

For the purpose of this question, c0r1 was assigned (elsewhere in the code) "x", which contained the values "A", "B", and "C"

Without getting much deeper into why things are the way they are, I need to get the values of foo.teal.x, and use those and "select" the respective values in c0r1.

When I use the following js:

```
var blah = foo.bar[0]; //blah = x
var value = foo.teal[0][blah][0]; //value = A
$("#c0r1").val(value);
```

Nothing is selected. I've stepped through with a debugger, blah and value are correctly assigned, and jQuery doesn't throw any errors... just, nothing gets assigned.

I've also tried

```
$("#c0r1[value='" + value + "']").attr("selected", "selected");
//and
$("#c0r1[value='" + value + "']").prop("selected", true);
```

Which were the suggestions I found elsewhere on the net.

Obviously, once I've got this working, I'll build up the code so that all the values are selected. By why is it not working, atm?

Elsewhere in the page, I've been able to use the .val() method with the same json object and select boxes, and it's worked fine. This is the first case of it being a "multiple", however.

Thanks,
Sam.

**UPDATE:**

Hmm, just had a thought: as the DOM elements c0r1 and its options are generated dynamically, is it possible that jQuery is not aware they exist? Although I assume that would throw an exception (which this code is not doing).

**UPDATE 2:**

I've worked it out, the issue had nothing to do with what was being discussed in this question, it's simply because the code to "select" the options was being run before the options had been received. The options are coming from a server response, it didn't occur to me that the above code would be called before the server response.

Looks like I fell for the old "latency is 0" fallacy my professors warned me about.

Feel free to downvote.

Comment: Have you tried passing the entire array of selections into `val()` instead of just the first item?  E.g.
`var values = foo.teal[0][blah];
$("#c0r1").val(values);`

Comment: I have, still no avail.

Comment: Hmm, just a shot in the dark:

I remember long ago having a problem with IE6 and setting the value of checkboxes.  I couldn't create a checkbox element in RAM, set the checked state, and then add it to the document.  Setting the checked state before the checkbox had been added to the document would always fail.

Are you trying to modify the select list before the browser has had a chance to render it into the document?  Also what browser(s) are you targetting?

Comment: Re: your update: No, jQuery will not throw an exception if it doesn't find any matching elements.  `$('#thisdoesnotexist').val('foobar')` will not throw an error.  (Apologies for the double-post, if it's inappropriate I'll remove it.)

Comment: By Jove, I think I've got it! Extremely silly error on my part, the values are actually coming from a server using a get request... because the data was instant to my eyes, it didn't occur to me that my setting code was being run /before/ the data was fully received. Damned computers are too fast for their own good, these days.

Comment: Your comment inspired me to actually look into the order in which things were being done, hence the upvote.

Answer (score 1):

You need commas between your objects in the `foo.teal` array:

```
 "foo" : {
       "bar": ["x", "y", "z"],
       "teal" : [
            {"x" : ["A"], "y" : [...], "z" : [...]}, // <-- here
            {"x" : [...], "y" : [...], "z" : [...]}, // <-- and here
            {"x" : [...], "y" : [...], "z" : [...]}
        ]
 }
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/gKvWj/

Comment: Sorry, I actually do have commas. The code in my question isn't actually the code in my system, for legality issues I had to change everything to more generic code. The commas got lost in translation.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting the wrong element with your jQuery selector. It should be the `option`, not the `select`, as such:

```
$('#c0r1 option[value="B"]').attr('selected', true);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this error, however it did not fix the code. This has lead to me to believe that it's not an issue with how I derive "value" (so, the object is valid).

Comment: I think you must be doing something else wrong then. Have you encapsulated your jQuery code within a document ready block? Can you post a jsfiddle of this *not* working? The one posted by AlienWebguy seems to work just fine...

Comment: use `prop()` method for `selected` not `attr()`...`selected` is a property not attribute

Comment: Hmm, just had a thought: as the DOM elements c0r1 and its options are generated dynamically, is it possible that jQuery is not aware they exist? Although I assume that would throw an exception (which this code is not doing).

Comment: jQuery won't throw an error in a case like this. If the selector matches nothing, the chaining does not error. Try this: in place of setting the value, write the length of the selected jQuery object to console, e.g. `console.log($("#c0r1 option[value='" + value + "']").length);`. It should be 1. If it is 0, you will know that either your selector doesn't match properly or the element doesn't exist in the document yet.